# Zabbix aggregate check Incorrect function expression

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to get an aggregated value over the latency from all datastores from all ESXi hosts.

I tried these variants of the [`grpmax` aggregation function](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/aggregate):

```
grpmax["Hypervisors","vmware.hv.datastore.read[{$URL},{HOST.HOST},,latency]",avg,600]
grpmax["Hypervisors","vmware.hv.datastore.read[,,,latency]",avg,600]
```

But for both I'm getting the error message:

> Incorrect function expression: grpmax["Hypervisors","vmware.hv.datastore.read[,,,latency]",avg,600]

How do I have to enter the keys so that zabbix finds them in the aggregation?

The keys of the items I want to aggregate look like this:

```
vmware.hv.datastore.read[{$URL},{HOST.HOST},datastore1,latency]
vmware.hv.datastore.read[{$URL},{HOST.HOST},datastore2,latency]
vmware.hv.datastore.read[{$URL},{HOST.HOST},datastore3,latency]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only aggregate items with the same key. In your example, you have `datastore1`, `datastore2` and `datastore3`. Zabbix aggregate items do not support wildcards, there is [a feature request](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1521) to allow that.

Comment: hm, are you sure about that? The example 2 in the documentation (`system.cpu.load[,avg1]`) suggests that elements in the key can be left empty, which I interpred as "use all" . Since I don't need to filter the datastores I don't need wildcards here.

Comment: That example expects items with the exact key to exist on the hosts in the target hostgroup. While parameters can be excluded in original items, the aggregate item must match the original key.